# Changing x-axis in grafana graph to custom time series sent as label of gauge

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, grafana

I am working on a project in java using spring boot that requires working on prometheus and grafana.

To send data to prometheus end-point, I am using "gauge" having name "metrices_value" with label "dateAndTime". This gauge contains value of type "Double".

Some examples of "gauge" at api end-point -

1. metrices_value{dateAndTime="2022-05-13 12:03:48"} 1.0
2. metrices_value{dateAndTime="2022-05-13 15:35:18"} 3.0

When I am using "Time series" visualization for "metrices_value" in grafana, then x-axis is showing the time at which prometheus is pulling the data from api end-point.

But, **on** **x-axis**, I want to **show the custom time that I am sending through gauge as a label i.e, "dateAndTime".**

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, a general comment about how you use labels. You should _never_ use the label values from an _unbounded_ sets of values. Meaning that in your implementation, every unique combination of metric name and labels (tags) will create a new instance of `Meter` which will slowly allocate all of your memory.

See more about labels at the Prometheus documentation: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/